# Pandas dataframe behavior: list(df) versus len(df)

Tags: python, dataframe, behavior

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
```

If I call `list` on this object, I get this:

```
>>> list(df)
['A', 'B']
```

But if I call `len` on this object, I get this:

```
>>> len(df)
3
```

The latter `len` call is more intuitive to me - it's like finding the number of elements in an iterable. I'm unclear what the exact difference in behavior is behind these two function calls on a `pandas.DataFrame`. The output from `dis.dis` looks very similar:

```
>>> dis.dis('len(df)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (len)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (df)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('list(df)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (df)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

So I haven't any indication as to why calling `list` on a DataFrame returns a list of column names while `len` returns the number of rows in the object. When I call `len(df)`, is [this method](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L768) being called on the `DataFrame`?

**Note: the `list` and `len` function comparisons are just an example. I'm really looking for information as to how `pandas.DataFrame`s interact/behave when interfacing with a variety of functions.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the definition of `__len__` in `pandas` `DataFrame` object:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.index)
```

so as expected, you get # of rows (I guess design decision?)

As for `list(df)`, it has to do with what `__iter__` returns, and in this case you can trace it back to `NDFrame` which is the baseclass of dataframes, and it says:

```
def __iter__(self):
    """Iterate over infor axis"""
    return iter(self._info_axis)
```

where `_info_axis` is the columns axis for DataFrames.

Comment: How does pandas "know" to call `__len__`, though, when I call `len(df)`? That behavior doesn't work, AFAIK, if I called a function `foo` on a `__foo__` method of an arbitrary object.

Comment: **pandas** doesn't know, but a python **class** knows. In other words, `__len__` is the magic method which any class can implement to define `len(<class_object>)`, much like `__ge__` is the magic method a class can implement to define the >= operator. Knowing that, `df` is nothing but an object of class `DataFrame`.